# Testing script or testing tool to find memory leak in binary executable code

Tags: c

I want to write script in c language for the testers to find the memory leak in embedded testing. Please help me out in writing script and which tool will use to run the script which will use to find the memory leak. I need to write the script for the testers who get only build to do the testing. Want to write the script in c language. The project is related to ipstack protocol.

Comment: C is not a scripting language

Comment: @heal: yes , c is not a scripting language. But

Comment: but ......? We are waiting

Comment: @heal: I need to write a script through testers can find the memory leak while testing.

Comment: You do not use a script - use valgrind/purify etc. Depends on platform

Comment: valgrind is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: @heal: as a developer I use valgrind. But how will use and can understand. I want script through tester will just come to know or find that there is a memory leak in the binary given by developers..I am trying to think as tester point of view not as a developer.

Comment: How to use valgrind and understand - Thua statement I said for the testers.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting run time errors, like memory leaks, in embedded systems can be a bit of an art.

Giving your testers a script might not be the best approach.

One of the single most effective tools for a programmer to detect the presence of runtime errors is a liberal use of assert statements in the source. Asserts are essentially free and are very easy to use.

Your testers will need to have some sort of stdout console. You will also need to give them a binary that was compiled with the ndebug symbol not defined or you will need to put a wrapper around assert that allows it to be left in the program when ndebug is defined. This may mean your testers need a debugger (some platforms push stdout through the JTAG or ICSP port by default), but giving them a binary may still be an option.

Here are some good things to do with assert: You should assert that pointers passed from function to function are in the range you expect them to be (to help detect stray, uninitialized, or just out of range pointers), you should assert that variables declared on the stack are still in the stack's defined range (to help detect stack overflows), you should assert that malloc never returns null if you are using dynamic memory (to help detect memory leaks), you should assert that memory just outside of any static data structure such as a ring buffer is not accidentally modified after you write to the buffer (to help detect index out of bounds issues), and you should assert that global variables/structures are initialized before you use them.

Otherwise there are a myriad of static analyzers geared towards embedded systems that perform abstract interpretation of C code and can aide in finding things like memory leaks, null pointer dereferences, division by zero, etc. These tools can get pretty pricey though. You can look into polyspace, frama-c, astree, escher c verifier, and there may be others. Some of these require annotations to tell the static analyzer a little bit about how you expect your code to operate.

If your problem is truly a memory leak then I have to ask: Why are you using dynamic memory in the first place? In an embedded system where all of the memory is accounted for, why can't you do what you need to do with static memory and the stack?

Comment: OP you should have thought of proving the code before you started. On the first embedded project, the objective is a minimal path from specification to implementation. But it's important to separate form from function and from platform. That way, you increase the debugging options, the ease of migration to other hardware, and emulation. As your problem is memory leaks and not hardware specific, this approach would have paid dividends.